# How to delete relational records in mutliple tables

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am tidying up an Access 2007 database with a central key table whose Primary key is a foreign key in numerous tables (about 20 in all) but the person who set this up obviously did not set up the constraints with DELETE CASCADE because when I attempt to delete a record in the central table I am warned of foreign key relations. Is there a way I can perform a delete and search through all tables deleting the relevant foreign key records.  It appears I cannot add DELETE CASCADE without recreating all the referential entegrity

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the relationship between each table by going to database tools -> relationship -> edit the relevant relationship between tables to make it cascade.